# SignalR GetHubContext method not firing hub method

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm trying to run a signalR hub method in one project from another project in the same solution. Both projects run on the same web front end.

When calling the following code, the code runs in the hub, up to the point where it expectantly errors due to not using an IHubContext object.

```
presentation.ChatHub ch = new ChatHub();
ch.Send(message, "", "");
```

When that happened, I changed my code to the following, however the code inside the hub no longer runs.

```
IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
context.Clients.All.Send(message, "", "");
```

The hub code is called as follows:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public int Send(string message, string fName, string IName)
    {
    //Code Goes here.
    }
```

Everything I have read including other answers on here seem to  point to getting the IhubContext then calling clients.all should work, yet I have no idea why it is not working

EDIT: i've changed my code so that a post is created in the database prior to running, and changed it so that it runs the 'broadcastMessage' function, which matches the javascript receiving end. yet that still doesn't wire up properly and javascript function is not hit.

```
   IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("chatHub");
   context.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(message, pid, userName, FirstName, count, "", "", nDate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this, but based on my understanding on the following page: [ASP.Net SignalR Hubs API](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub)
It is saying that when you call a method from outside the hub in, you aren't calling the method you have defined on the hub, instead you are telling the hub to activate the jquery on all of the connected clients.

This is why you aren't seeing your hub method activating.

Comment: okay, ive changed my code to create a post, then the hub code that so that it matches my javascript. and the two still arent connecting. i'll update my post now, any ideas?

Comment: The link I've provided was what I used to help me when I had the same problem. It took a while to get it to work but I started with having two pages in my site, one that I used to manually test the standard hub and ensure that was working. Then my actual main page that utilised the controller action. Make sure that your jquery method name is the same and it is the same one in you hub method and your action method as jquery is case sensitive.

Comment: yeah, I've read through it and my code seems to line up with what it says, i'm going to keep investigating, thanks for your help

Comment: Good luck, maybe someone else will be able to shed light on it for you. Oh, make sure your page is including the ~SignalR/Hubs jquery reference. I forgot that on one page and took ages to find out why it wasn't working :-)

Comment: yeah, the page has signalR working on it already for a newsfeed. My aim is that whenever an item is uploaded the newsfeed is automatically updated. and im doing that on the serverside. so the signalr reference is already working. with the same function, with the same name.